# SQL - Uso do Distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

Amigos preciso de um Select que carregue:
(todos os portais vinculados a um usuário e uma coluna adicional informando quais portais foram selecionados em uma determinada notícia)

Até o momento meu SQL está assim...:

```
select 
   distinct 
   case when usudesc.txt_nome is null then 0 else 1 end as MeusPortais,
   case when nopo.id_noticia is null then 0 else 1 end as PotalSelecionado,
   porti.id_portal, nopo.id_noticia, porti.txt_apelido
from tb_portal porti 
   left join tb_noticiasportais nopo on nopo.id_portal = porti.id_portal 
       and nopo.id_noticia = '26' 
   left join tb_usuarioportal usu on usu.id_portal = porti.id_portal 
       and usu.id_usuario = '1' 
   left join tb_usuario usudesc on usudesc.id_usuario = usu.id_usuario
   left join tb_noticias noti on noti.id_noticia = nopo.id_noticia
order by porti.txt_apelido asc
```

A base tem essa estrutura:

**tb_noticias**(id_noticia, txt_titulo)

---

**tb_noticiasportais** (id_noticia, id_portal)

---

**tb_portal** (id_portal, txt_titulo)

---

**tb_usuarioportal**(id_usuario, id_portal)

---

**tb_usuario**(id_usuario, txt_usuario)

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVIDO:**

```
select * from (
    select 
    distinct 
    case when usudesc.txt_nome is null then 0 else 1 end as MeusPortais,
    case when nopo.id_noticia is null then 0 else 1 end as PotalSelecionado,
    porti.id_portal, nopo.id_noticia, porti.txt_apelido
from tb_portal porti 
    left join tb_noticiasportais nopo on nopo.id_portal = porti.id_portal 
    and nopo.id_noticia = '26' 
    left join tb_usuarioportal usu on usu.id_portal = porti.id_portal 
    and usu.id_usuario = '1' 
    left join tb_usuario usudesc on usudesc.id_usuario = usu.id_usuario
    left join tb_noticias noti on noti.id_noticia = nopo.id_noticia
) as U
where U.MeusPortais = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
porti.id_portal, nopo.id_noticia, porti.txt_apelido, usudesc.txt_usuario, noti.txt_titulo
from tb_portal porti 
left join tb_noticiasportais nopo on nopo.id_portal = porti.id_portal 
and nopo.id_noticia = 26 
left join tb_usuarioportal usu on usu.id_portal = porti.id_portal 
left join tb_usuario usudesc on usudesc.id_usuario = usu.id_usuario
left join tb_noticias noti on noti.id_noticia = nopo.id_noticia
order by porti.txt_apelido asc
```

Comment: Amigo... não é bem isso.
Mas me deu uma linha de raciocínio: